# SetTimeout to remove instance of object from document

Tags: jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

Need some help with `setTimeout()` method.

I have the following code here:

I need to be able to remove an instance of the newState variable. Think I am doing it wrong. Please assist. Thanks in advance.

```
var deleteState = setTimeout("alert('Object has been removed')" , 2000);
newState.mousedown(function(e) {
    if (deleteState == 0) {
        clearTimeout(deleteState);
    }

    jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($(this));
    $(this).remove();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: BTW what is the question?

Comment: I think you should move your `var deleteState =  setTimeout` var inside the `mousedown` event.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
var deleteState = setTimeout(function(){alert('Object has been removed') } , 2000);
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp